# How to define index signature for a type alias of a Map in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0, typing

If I have defined a type for a `Map` like this:

```
type MyCustomMap = Map<string, number>;
```

How can I add an index signature so that I can set key-values after creation? I have been able to do such thing with types that define different attributes such as:

```
type MyCustomObj = {
    [key: string]: any;
    something: string;
}
```

But I could not find a way to do it in above's case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```js
type MyCustomObj<Key extends string | number, Value, Rest = {}> =
    Key extends string ? { [key: string]: Value } & Rest: { [key: number]: Value } & Rest;
```

And you can use it like that:

```js
type Obj = MyCustomObj<string, number>;
type CustomObj = MyCustomObj<string, number, { key: boolean }>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20MyCustomObj%3CKey%20extends%20string%20%7C%20number%2C%20Value%2C%20Rest%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Key%20extends%20string%20%3F%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Value%20%7D%20%26%20Rest%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20number%5D%3A%20Value%20%7D%20%26%20Rest%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Obj%20%3D%20MyCustomObj%3Cstring%2C%20number%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20CustomObj%20%3D%20MyCustomObj%3Cstring%2C%20number%2C%20%7B%20key%3A%20boolean%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A)